# Android Layout textview (Margin/padding) issue in Samsung Galaxy S3 Version 4.3

Tags: android-layout, textview, android

Its a kind of Chat Screen, Textview contains the image(9-Patch Image) as the Background drawable.
All the devices its working perfectly. 
Please refer the Image:

[image: All devices in Version 4.4 & version 5]

Problem which is encountered is that in Android 4.3 in Samsung S3, the Image(9-Patch) is unable to take the Margin or Padding for textview. The Background Image is not getting stretch to give margin. Please refer Image :

[image]

i have tried all margin but it only doesn't reflect in Android 4.3. Is it device specific or Android 4.3 bug?

How can i solve this?

Comment: Is the background 9patch? Could you add it to the question?

Comment: @Lamorak - Yes, its a 9-patch image which expands according to the Text.

Comment: Could you provide the 9 patch image?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6OumkvXLSc-Y3hLLThIdHJyOFU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

When using a 9-patch image as a background you don't have to set margin/padding to the inner view. The content area of the 9-patch is defined in the right and bottom 1 pixel stripe. Yours image has a content area set on all of it and that results in the behavior reffered in the question.

Try this image with correctly set content area:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was just to set padding programatically, for instance:

```
int leftRightPadding = ctx.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.message_chat_padding_left_right);
int bottomTopPadding = ctx.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.message_chat_padding_bottom_top);
text.setPadding(leftRightPadding, bottomTopPadding, leftRightPadding, bottomTopPadding);
```